# OpenCL kernel long execution time, I split it to avoid timeouts but they still happen

Tags: windows, kernel, opencl

I have this OpenCL kernel that, depending on the parameters, can take a long time to execute. I then get some kind of timeout errors (no message, but the screen flickers and things crash). I tried a few approaches to disable timeouts, but nothing worked. So I tried splitting the kernel. Instead of one long kernel call I now do several calls each with shorter execution time. This is adjustable and I tried different "lengths" (more calls, less time per call), but this doesn't make much of a difference. I still get a flickering screen and sometimes crashes (although a little less frequent).

Shouldn't this approach work? So windows and other tasks should have the GPU responding to them between kernel calls? Or do I need to put a `Sleep` command between kernel calls? What would be the appropriate way to tackle a kernel that takes to long?

**Edit**

I maybe should mention that timeouts occur only if the overall time (no matter the number of kernel calls during that time) goes beyond a few seconds.

**Edit 2**

For people with similar problems reading this: It actually solved the problem when I put (in the case of C++) `Sleep` between kernel calls. This seems to give the GPU enough time to respond to Windows. As little as 5ms were enough.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout crash is a Windows bug. Windows on some computers will kill any single GPU kernel that runs for longer than 2 seconds, and reset the graphics driver, hence the screen flickering.

The solution: In Windows Registry (Win+R, regedit, Enter) in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers, create a 32-bit DWORD named TdrDelay and set its decimal value to 300. This increases the threshold to reset the graphics driver from 2 seconds to 5 minutes (= 300 seconds). Don't forget to reboot the PC after the registry modification.

Comment: But shouldn't splitting the kernel, so no single kernel takes more than 2 seconds solve this problem?

Comment: @Paul Aner yes, but not always. If you have 2M workgroups and split them to 2x 1M workgroups, kernel runtime will approximately half. If it's only 20 workgroups with mostly serial work, not saturating the parallel hardware, runtime will not half. Whenever you run the splitted kernels on a slower GPU, runtime might be above 2 seconds again.

Comment: But as stated above: I can easily adjust the runtime of a kernel. So even if one kernel call never exceeds 2 seconds runtime, if multiple calls do, I get a timeout. What can I do about this (except putting the whole program to sleep, so the GPU gets a chance to respond to Windows)?

Comment: Does removing the timeout fix it? Because the described behaviour can also occur if you've got a bug in your kernel that's causing memory overwrites on older GPUs and/or systems without an active IOMMU.